# Problems with import AOO Base 4.0.1

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, openoffice-base

I have a problem with import largish ( more then 200000 records) tables to Apache OpenOffice Base. The error message is:

```
State SQL: S1000
Error code: 98
java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException in statement [
    INSERT INTO "Street_sc_suburb_st" (
        "ID","Street_ID","StreetType_ID","suburb_city_rd_ID"
    ) VALUES (
        ?,?,?,?
    )
]
```

I import tables from another AOO Base, connected to database in MS Access, by using CTRL-C/Ctrl-V. How can I avoid this problem?
Thank you for help!

Comment: Is the error message complete? If not, could you please add a complete stacktrace? Did you test other ways to import the data (e.g. SQL `INSERT`)?

Comment: With tables, which contain near 100000, this method works OK.

Comment: Error: State SQL: S1000
Error code: 98

java.io.IOException: java.lang.NullPointerException in statement [INSERT INTO "Street_sc_suburb_st" ( "ID","Street_ID","StreetType_ID","suburb_city_rd_ID") VALUES ( ?,?,?,?)]

Comment: It works OK with Insert into table1 from table2 ( but doesn't with  insert into ... values ...), but i can't find right way  if table2 in another database.

Comment: AFAIK there's still no way to create a query involving multiple databases - there's an [RFE since 2005](https://issues.apache.org/ooo/show_bug.cgi?id=42464) and part of the [feature wish list in the wiki](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Base/Features/Pool)...

Comment: I'm so stupid! The solution ( of my problem) is so simple! it doesn't work with large table, so I can devide them( thanks i have only two large tables) into parts, import to new database and unite. And it works great! Thanks for your help!